How to bring a campaign together?
I have recently started preparing a 5e campaign and I'm having a very difficult time figuring out how to bring all the players together to form a group. It's just a really daunting task trying to naturally bring the group together and give them some kind of reason for them to stick together and help achieve each others goals.
The Setting
The campaign is set in a single steampunk style city split into 5 districts with each district corresponding with each main caste

District 1 is rampant with poverty and different people just trying to take advantage of the unfortunate
District 2 is inhabited by the middle/working class members of society
District 3 is where the merchants live
District 4 is the where the people of noble heritage lives

Overall each of these districts are managed by a corrupt baron who is looking to strengthen his grasp on the city and stop the people from rising up against him. I am really hoping that I can get the players invested in either assisting The Baron or overthrowing him.
There are four characters and each of them correspond with a different district which is the main reason for the difficulties behind bringing them together. They are all hopefully starting on one of the trains that run through each of the districts which will be raided by a group of the Barons men. The thing I want help in is a way to giving each character a reason to band together and follow each other on the path they choose.
Are there any tools or some kind of pre-made encounter that I could use in such a way to get the adventure started naturally without just throwing the group together with real reason for them to stay together?

I think this question could use more details.  It's hard to answer without knowing the group size, setting details, and what plot hooks you're interested in presenting.

Those are good changes, thank you.  I've voted to reopen.

@NotArch while that question's answers are going to be useful, I believe it's not a duplicate question since I'm not looking to have them all bonded before the gameplay starts, I'm hoping that something in the first session will be what causes them to join together (I apologize if this comment isnt coherent I've chosen night time to make the comment) while searching through that question and it's answers it didn't really have any encounters or certain dm tools to get them meeting in the session, it focused on setting guidelines for character creation so they've meet in backstory

“Are there any tools or some kind of pre-made encounter” Both of these questions are off topic for this site.

Hi @Argo I'm a bit confused: isn't a "pre-made encounter" and getting an adventure "started naturally" a contradiction? I was thinking about this and how to answer your question but I'm struggling with that. Could you clarify what you mean?

@Senmurv I guess I'm having a hard time putting into words what kind of help I'm looking for tbh

If you want characters to stick together, they all need a shared goal.
You're saying your players can choose character goals after the campaign gets started (either to assist or overthrow the Baron). This isn't going to work. There's no way to guarantee that different characters won't pick different sides and split the party, unless you have strong connections in the backstory (e.g. a best friend may sacrifice their own desires for the sake of their friendship). You could have the Baron keep his supporters as spies in the party to keep them physically together, but it's going to create a weird PvP situation.
Your other option is to play the Baron in a way that you know will motivate all your PCs to choose the same side. But you still need to make sure that the PC's alignments are compatible before the campaign starts.

Thanks for your answer and I agree in principle, but what's your experience of when PCs to not follow a shared goal. Just stating it doesn't make it so. But, I certainly have played in games where there were deviations form goals and it worked. Sometimes, we didn't stick together - much to our DM's chagrin. :D But, she was awesome at managing it.

@Thank-Glob Stating it does make it so if it's something the DM enforces. OP clearly wants the PCs to band together which is more common than not.
The players also have a responsibility to make sure everyone has fun, not just the DM, and the DM is included in "everyone". If your DM is open to the party splitting, that's fine, but it's poor form to knowingly make the game less fun for anyone at the table

I would look at Murder in Baldur's Gate, which uses an analogous setup with the Upper City, the Lower City, and the Outer City in Baldur's Gate. The campaign rules for the module do a very good job of setting up class conflict along with the main plot. Many of the encounters in MiBG could be easily converted to a steampunk setting.
